# jQuery how to combine "disable cut and paste script" with radio button list?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following script to disable "cut and paste" on my form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.employeeEmailConfirm, .emailConfirm').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      alert('thou. shalt. not. PASTE!');
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Taken from the following thread: [How to disable Paste (Ctrl+V) with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-ctrlv-paste-with-jquery)

But I don't want to display the "alert" I want to display hidden div's.

However, my form has radio button list and some form elements are shown or hidden depending on which value is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// attach event to employee radio buttons 
$("span.isEmployee").find("input").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $(".aboutyou").show();
        $(".yourdetails").show();
        $(".referrer").hide();
        $(".security").show();
        $(".signup").show();
        $("#emailTr").show();
        $("#employeeEmailMessage1").show();
        $("#employeeEmailMessage2").hide();
        $("#employeeEmailRetype").show();
        $("#nonemployeeEmail").hide();
        $("#nonemployeeEmailRetype").hide();
        $("#emailMessageSubBrand").show();
        SetEmailEnableDisable(true);
    } else {
        $(".aboutyou").show();
        $(".yourdetails").show();
        $(".referrer").show();
        $(".security").show();
        $(".signup").show();
        $("#emailTr").hide();
        $("#employeeEmailMessage1").hide();
        $("#employeeEmailMessage2").hide();
        $("#employeeEmailRetype").hide();
        $("#nonemployeeEmail").show();
        $("#nonemployeeEmailRetype").show();
        $("#emailMessageSubBrand").hide();
        SetEmailEnableDisable(false);
    }
});
```

How do I combine the "cut copy paste" script with my show/hide radio button list?

My failed attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.employeeEmailConfirm, .emailConfirm').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      alert('thou. shalt. not. PASTE!');
      $("span.isEmployee").find("input").click(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == "1") {
              $("#employeeEmailMessage2").show();
              } else {
                 $("#nonemployeeEmailMessage").show();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.isEmployee").find("input").click(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $('.employeeEmail, .employeeEmailConfirm').bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
                $("#employeeEmailMessage2").show();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        } else {
            $('.email, .emailConfirm').bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
                $("#nonemployeeEmailMessage").show();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });
});
```