# How to prevent user pasting text in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have this JS function that prevents user from typing characters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if(!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>

<span>Radio Receive:</span>
<input name="ReceiveNo" type="text" class="txtbox" onkeypress='validate(event)' maxlength="11" value="${cpCon.receiveNo}" required tabindex="34" />
```

But I noticed that when the user tried to paste a word from this textbox, the text can be entered. How can I prevent this without disabling the paste?

Comment: `<input readonly>` or `inputElement.readonly = true`?

Comment: Check out the [onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) event for blocking control characters.

Comment: check this similar question.. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-ctrlv-paste-with-jquery

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Very Easy Solution:**

```
<input name="ReceiveNo" type="text" class="txtbox" onkeypress='validate(event)' maxlength="11" value="${cpCon.receiveNo}" required tabindex="34" onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="return false" autocomplete=off />
```

This worked for me very well. No one can paste now into your textbox using right button paste option of mouse or pressing ctrl+v from the keyboard.

Comment: Great. I couldn't add the onPaste directly so had to add it with JavaScript:  $("#stopPaste").attr("onPaste", "return false"); and that seems to do the trick

Comment: These techniques are all fairly simple to bypass if one has a small amount of know-how (dev tools -> delete node -> recreate node), so don't depend on them to work.

Comment: It's 2020 and onPaste="return false" still works, YEAH BABY!!

Comment: This does not prevent pasting on Firefox/Linux at least.  Using event.preventDefault() did work though.

Comment: Why not just a simple onPaste="return false"?

Comment: The user can still copy by dragging text they've typed out of the field (or cutting it), so `ondragstart="return false"` and `oncut="return false"` may be worth adding as well. Then again, the user can open the console and use `document.querySelector(".txtbox").value = "foo"` if they really want to get text in. Minor nitpick, but HTML attributes should be lower case, and values should be quoted. This is the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26255397/6243352) but without citation of the [original(?) source](https://sumtips.com/how-to/prevent-copy-cut-paste-text-field/).

Answer (score 26):

// To Disable the paste functionality

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

// Below One might be helpful for your functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
    validate(e);
  });
});
```

**or**

`OnTabOut()` or `onblur()` you can validate the entered / pasted text instead of handling the paste functionality.

Comment: what if I dont want to disable paste option? I only want to prevent user from typing or pasting characters.

Comment: try to bind the your validation's (preventing the characters) to paste option like II case in the answer.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont know exaclty how to implement JS function...I tried your second option and It can disable paste option...But I dont want to disbale this...I only want to prevent character in my textbox

Comment: `OnTabOut()` no longer exists as it was deprecated in I believe 2015...

Answer (score 5):

I tried this in my Angular project and it worked fine without jQuery.

```
<input type='text' ng-paste='preventPaste($event)'>
```

And in script part:

```
$scope.preventPaste = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
};
```

In non angular project, use 'onPaste' instead of 'ng-paste' and 'event' instead of '$event'.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need non editable kendoComboBox(), you could use kendoDropDownList() instead.

In my case i needed it to be enabled/disabled depending on user privileges,
so here's the solution i came up with (this prevents key inputs and pasting values) :

```
if (user.hasRight()) {

  var myinput = $("#myinput").data("kendoComboBox");
  myinput.input.on("keydown", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
  myinput.input.bind("paste", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });

}
```

You can test it [here](http://refork.com/x4bd)

Answer (score 1):

**VanillaJS solution**

```js
function pasteNotAllowFunc(xid){
 let myInput = document.getElementById(xid);
     myInput.onpaste = (e) => e.preventDefault();
} 

pasteNotAllowFunc('pasteInput')
```

```html
Paste
<input id="pasteInput" value="paste not allow"/>
<hr/>
Textarea
<textarea id="test" value="Copy me and try to paste"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" name="ReceiveNo" id="ReceiveNo" class="form-control"  required oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" autocomplete=off />
```

***JQUERY***

```
$('#email').bind("cut copy paste drag drop",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

To bind behavior of the element on cut, copy, paste drag and drop and prevent default.

Answer (score -4):

jQuery:

```
    $(this).click(function () {
    $(".txtbox").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

  });
```

or css:

```
.txtbox{
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
```

or html attribute:

```
 set disabled="disabled";
```

Comment: if you use this, user will not be able to type in the textbox