# Antd Disable Paste Event on Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I want to disable paste event on input box in Ant design. i didn't find a correct solution yet. Thanks in advance

i used this and worked

```
                    inputOriginclick = () => {
                   this.myOriginRef.current.input.onpaste = () => {
                    return false;
                  };
                    };
                    <Input
                        value={this.state.origin}
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Enter City'
                        ref={this.myOriginRef}
                        onClick={this.inputOriginclick}
                        onChange={e => this.handleChage('origin', e)}
                      
                      />
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this solution found here [How to prevent user pasting text in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320069/how-to-prevent-user-pasting-text-in-a-textbox?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
  <input
    name="somename"
    type="text"
    value=""
    required
    onCopy={false}
    onDrag={false}
    onDrop={false}
    onPaste={false}
    autocomplete="off"
/>
```

Comment: i am using antd input it wasnt supporting 'return false'

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function() {
 const noPaste = document.getElementById('nopaste');
 noPaste.onpaste = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="nopaste">
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action by using [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
<Input
  type='text'
  onPaste={e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
  }}
/>
```

Use this props to block copy

```
onCopy={e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  return false
}}
```

Thought will be helpful in the future. even though question asked long time back.