# Accept only numbers in Textbox - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a functionality for a textbox to allow only numbers. I have written the following code, but using Ctrl + V we are able to paste text. How can we prevent this.

```
$('.numeric-textbox').live('keypress', function (e) {
    if ((e.keyCode < 48) || (e.keyCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Can someone suggest some solution. :)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in 1.7, and removed *entirely* in 1.9 (replaced with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Comment: @ASTEROID why are you using 1.6.2? any reason not to update and pull the latest `/1/` version?

Comment: Old Application. Requirement.. Standard.. Whatever they call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.numeric-textbox').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
```

This will prevent cut copy paste event on your textbox

Comment: @A.Wolff If u want you can remove it

Comment: I would also disallow to paste only numbers?

Comment: @Nitinvarpe Now I can enter anything in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : You can disable the CTRL +V  [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-ctrlv-paste-with-jquery)

Option 2 : Put the regex validation on lost focus or keyup to