# How to detect 'cut' event in IE10 and Safari 9.1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect copy,cut and contextmenu behavior with jQuery.
Here is my code.

```
  $('pre.text').on('contextmenu cut copy', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('no copy!');
  });
```

But "cut"event was not working in IE10 and Safari.
How can i solve that?

Comment: What element is `.text`?

Comment: Element of '.text' is <pre> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Paste (Ctrl+V) with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-paste-ctrlv-with-jquery)

Comment: It is similar. But I can't solve that.