# Disable alert message with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me how to disable the alert message in the following code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).keydown(function(event) { 
        var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();        
        if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "v")) {
            alert('Sorry, This Functionality Has Been Disabled!'); 
            //disable key press processing
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

We have a chat site and we want to disable CTRL+V, for Firefox users it displays a popup message saying "Sorry, This Functionality Has Been Disabled!"
and also it gives an option of "prevent this page from creating additional dialogues" and once you click that, then Users can use CTRL+v

Can we disable this message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Paste (Ctrl+V) with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-paste-ctrlv-with-jquery)

Comment: Why cant you just remove that line of code?

Comment: Do you realize that paste is more than ctrl+v? right click, edit/paste.... etc

Comment: So you really want to actually disable copy/cut from the page, its not about the alert message. I think we should close this, as it doesnt really make sense.

Comment: I think OP want the popup to appear once and once it's appeared to stop. Though it's not clear. You probably want to look at [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Do you only want to show the message the first time, and them prevent the paste from happening but not show the message again ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're not going to like this answer:

It's not really possible to totally prevent the user from accessing their clipboard, this cannot be completely controlled with JS as the functionality is sandboxed by the OS.

You can confuse the user by binding the key presses and doing other things, but you cannot actually prevent them from copy and pasting. You can also just not call `alert` altogether if you want to quietly ignore those key-presses.

Comment: well they are not putting data onto their clipboard here ;)

Comment: um, how's that? (changed to "accessing")

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you only want to show the message the first time and then keep blocking the action but not show the message.

So, you need a flag of whether you have shown the message

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var notifiedCtrlV = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(event) { 
        var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();        
        if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "v")) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!notifiedCtrlV) alert('Sorry, This Functionality Has Been Disabled!'); 
            notifiedCtrlV = true;
            //disable key press processing
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```